# Indicating a WhatsApp message is received, via the Twilio API, in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, twilio, whatsapp

We are creating a service that will receive WhatsApp messages via the Twilio service. This works, but our issue is that we can't work out how to tell the sender that our server has 'read' the message. The messages always appear as being 'delivered' and never 'read', even after responding to the message. We have looked in the [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/api), but can't seem to see how to do this.

Our server is written in NodeJS and is using Express for HTTP side.

Below is an equivalent of the code we are using (not a running example):

```
import { twiml } from 'twilio';

const { MessagingResponse } = twiml;

async receiveMessage(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {

   const message = req.body;

   // Send back an empty response, we will process asynchronously
   const immediateResponse = new MessagingResponse();
   res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/xml');
   res.send(immediateResponse.toString());

   // TODO indicate message as read

   // Do what ever logic is needed for given message
   const replyMessage = await processMessage(message);

   const messageToTwilio = {
     body: replyMessage,
     from: message.To,
     to: message.From
   };

   const twilioResponse = await this.client.messages.create(messageToTwilio);

   // Record value of twilioResponse in DB
}
```

Can anyone suggest what in the API I should be using for this?

Comment: Do you respond with Twilio Markup Language (TwiML)? https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/twiml. I cannot seem to reproduce.

Comment: The `res.send` sends an empty `MessagingResponse` and then we send back using the twilio client. We do it this way to avoid a timeout on the Twilio call to us, since there can be a delay in processing.The MessagingResponse doesn't have any status fields that we could see. As for 'Status callbacks' they are only for messages sent to the client.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Twilio on this issue and it turns out this is not currently possible. While they consider this a useful functionality, it is not currently a priority for implementation.

Note, It is possible to get the delivery status of outgoing messages, via the status webhook, but it is not possible to indicate to the remote party that the incoming message was 'read'.